# visual studio express : free class diagram tool

Tags: c#, class, diagrams

I am using c# express and would like to use a free tool to design my class diagrams. What do you recommend for a free tool?

Answer (score 13):

There is also [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/), which is quite new, probably not ready for large projects, but looks promising.

**Edit**: This tool is not new anymore and unfortunately it isn't actively maintained since a while. Last release was on 30 Jul 2010.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I wanted something like Visual Studio class diagrams, so I can write code at design time and build diagrams from it. Visual Studio Express lacks class diagrams, but NClass (with assembly import) is just the ticket!

Answer (score 3):

You should also check out [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/). It's great and free!

Comment: Heads up....This is completely unable to work with C# in Visual Studio 2010. I wasted 30 minutes trying it.

Answer (score 2):

With or without code generation?

Without I know [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) and [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). Also, you might wanna dig through [this list](http://design.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old question but at least for the past few years [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) can be used to create class diagrams. Not as good as VS but comparable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and welcome to [so]! Unfortunately, the question you're answering appears to be off-topic, and standards has changed over time. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JUDE?

http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/index.html

Comment: That one doesn't look free, as per the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

I use [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). Its simple but has just enough functionality. It does not generate code.