# generating class diagram in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, express, class-diagram

I am relatively new to C# and I want to generate class diagram of my project. Can anybody tell me how to generate class diagram in visual studio 2010 express.I know that it is easy to do it on ultimate version. But what about express version? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess Class Diagram facility is not available in express version.

Read [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661685/visual-studio-express-free-class-diagram-tool&ei=6L57Ue6VFof3rQeU2ICgAQ&usg=AFQjCNEI2XonXtcQpEDtYw46WwS6JM31Cg&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bmk&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Express Version does not have "class-diagram" features. You going to have to do it cave-man style