# VS 2010 Express - how to generate UML diagrams from code?

Tags: c#, .net, uml, visual-studio-2010

I have c# code and need to generate UML diagrams of it.

How to do it in Visual Studio 2010 Express edition?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409445%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) concerns only Ultimate Edition. Some older answers suggests tools but none of them works with .NET 4.0.

Any ideas how to create diagrams from code?

**Update:**

This question has been marked as duplicate, however I'd like to point that I'm not looking for a UML tool in general but a tool that can create diagrams *from code*. I'm not very happy with answers both from this question or suggested one. Here are the reasons:

- only Software Ideas Modeller is able to generate diagrams directly from code, others do it from exe or dll file.
- reverse engineered diagrams are barely usable
- tools have some very important usage limitations and due to complexity are not easy to operate

Anyway, thanks you for answers and suggestions. It seems that old fashioned pencil and piece of paper works best in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in the express version.

Try [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/). Not sure if it supports .NET 4.0 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661685/visual-studio-express-free-class-diagram-tool).

Comment: tried it, but it crashes on my code

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce).

Installation Guide: [Installation](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/2381/2383/66562_overviewandi.html)